# Why does php function asXML() include html tags in the response?

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax, simplexml

I am creating a PHP script to return the file structure of a directory as an XML document. I have used simpleXML to do this, and the script is working, but the response is nested in HTML tags.

PHP file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<body>



<?php
$xml_string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<directory>
</directory>
XML;
$directory=new SimpleXMLElement($xml_string);

Code creating the file structure.    

echo $directory->asXML();


?>

</body>
</html>
```

The response is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<body>

<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<directory>
XML tags created by script
</directory>

</body>
</html>
```

I am wondering why the XML is inside an HTML document. I can't get any javascript to access the XML elements.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("folder");
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlDoc[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

*(snippets of the Javascript code used)*

I get an error: 'xmlhttp.responeXML is undefined'

Is there any way of interpreting the response or not having the XML nested inside HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the code generating the xml is surrounded by html. Remove the html parts and you should be fine.

Remove this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<body>
```

And this:

```
</body>
</html>
```